# PHP: How to count how many times a specific day is between two days?

Tags: php, datetime

I need to count how many times some specific days appears between two given dates. For example, I need to know how many Tuesday are between `01/03/2010 12:12:55` and `06/04/2011 16:55:20`.

So far, I can calculate the number of days (all days) between to dates with this (The dates are given in `d/m/Y g:i:s` format):

```
<?php
  function calculateDiffTime($startDate, $endDate = false)
  {
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i:s', $startDate);
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i:s', $endDate);

    // Calculando la diferencia entre las dos fechas.
    $interval = $startDate->diff($endDate);

    return $interval->format('%a days'); // Return '# days'
  }
?>
```

What I want to do is calculate the difference between the total of days (the result of the function above) and the number of times the specific day (s) appears.

Comment: Nice, I Like this. Let me try to make something for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[how to find number of mondays or tuesdays between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653891/how-to-find-number-of-mondays-or-tuesdays-between-two-dates)

Not my response but a quick google search popped that up =P