# Calculate amount of weeks after a certain date

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently trying to calculate the amount of periods (each period is 1 week, after a certain date or day). Lets say first period start on 01-01-2013 (tuesday) until 29-01-2013 (tuesday)(4 periods in total).

I have a table that looks like:

```
id | startDate (datetime) | endDate (datetime)
```

I have two input fields where a user can fill in a `start date` and `end date`. I would like to fill any date between `01-01-2013` and `29-01-2013` and decide how many times it passes a tuesday (the date the period starts) again.

So if I would select `01-01-2013 until 07-01-2013` would result in: `1`, but if i would select `06-01-2013 till 09-01-2013` this would result in `2` and `06-01-2013 till 16-01-2013` would result in `3` etc.

To be clear, I dont want to know the amount of weeks between the two dates, only the amount of times it 'crosses' the same day (tuesday) that was given in the database. Every period is 1 week. Is there anyone that could help me out?

Comment: For clarifications, you want to know how many times X day (Tuesday) falls between dates Y and Z?

Comment: yep! thats exactly what im looking for, and i cant get my head around it

Comment: Search! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653891/how-to-find-number-of-mondays-or-tuesdays-between-two-dates

Comment: Try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff   and/or the many other mysql date functions.

Comment: mkaatman, thanks for your answer, sorry i did search but i couldnt find it, probably was using the wrong keywords. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's `date()` function.

```
$startday = strtotime($start_date_from_db);//date from db;
$endday = strtotime($end_date_from_db);//date from db;
$counter = 0;
for($i=$startday; $i<=$endday; $i+=86400) {
    $current_day = date('w', $i);
    if($current_day == 2) { //0 for sunday, 1 for monday, 2 for tuesday
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: rather wasteful, especially if it's a "large" date range. there's easier ways to get date range lengths.

Comment: @MarcB In OP's example, the difference between start date and end date is only two months. So it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing dates a good method is:

1- transform the dates to timestamps:

```
$timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);
```

2- do the desired operation, in this case:

```
$timebetween = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;
```

3- Transform result (number of seconds) to desired value, in this case:

```
$weeks= $timebetween / 604800;
```