# How to calculate number of mondays in a given month?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, date

```
    $start = strtotime("tuesday UTC"); 
    $end = strtotime("3 tuesday UTC");      
    echo date("m/d/Y", $start). " - ".date("m/d/Y", $end). " has ". countDays(0, $start, $end). " Sundays";
```

I found this solution . But countDays is not working .

I found the solution ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653891/how-to-find-number-of-mondays-or-tuesdays-between-two-dates

Comment: I got the solution ....it is very simple ..