# how to count how many Tuesdays and Wednesdays between two dates?

Tags: regex, date, google-sheets, count, sum

The input is an array `[Tuesday, Wednesday]` but it is should be stored in one cell only.
Using this input I want to know how many days between two dates.

I found a reference but I don't know how to make it as dynamic because it only accept integer weekday.

https://www.extendoffice.com/excel/formulas/excel-count-day-of-week-between-two-dates.html

> SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(start_date&":"&end_date)))=week_day))

Someone knows how to achieve this?

---

**EDITED:** input is okay in any format as long as it should inside in one cell only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of Mondays in a given date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range) or [how to find number of mondays or tuesdays between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653891/how-to-find-number-of-mondays-or-tuesdays-between-two-dates)

Comment: @Luuk this could be the answer. but I'm looking for google sheet formula. the links you provided based from languages (i have no idea, how to do it)

Comment: Maybe check the documentation for weekday to find out how that function works? The docs is available here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(TEXT(SEQUENCE(DAYS(B2, B1)+1, 1, B1), 
 "dddd"), REGEXREPLACE(A4, ", ?", "|")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

within sheets you can try:

***For count:***

`=INDEX(LAMBDA(aix,COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(aix,REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(WEEKDAY(aix)),JOIN("|",MATCH(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A5,"\[|\]",""),", "),TEXT(SEQUENCE(7),"DDDD"),0)))))))(SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"d")+1,1,A2,1)))`

***For list:***

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(aix,IFNA(FILTER(aix,REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(WEEKDAY(aix)),JOIN("|",MATCH(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A5,"\[|\]",""),", "),TEXT(SEQUENCE(7),"DDDD"),0))))))(SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"d")+1,1,A2,1)))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: solution is working but kind of long. but i upvoted because first answer. thank you.