# Calculate number of Mondays in a given month (PHP)

Tags: php, date, calendar

I need a (automatically populate a form field) PHP function which will return a value of either 4 or 5 for a given month, which represents the number of Mondays in that month (calendar weeks).
Cheers

Comment: Interesting question, but what have you tried?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069966/in-php-how-to-know-how-many-mondays-have-passed-in-this-month-uptil-today

Comment: Start by getting the day of the 1st

Comment: "not a real question"? "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form"? Seriously?

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321668/find-how-many-sunday-from-2-given-dates

Comment: Exactly the same  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653891/how-to-find-number-of-mondays-or-tuesdays-between-two-dates

Comment: Each month for a given year has a certain number of Mondays, e.g. this month has 5, whilst next month has 4...So if I pass today's date I will get a return value 5 (Janurary 2012 has 5 Mondays/Calendar weeks 1 to 5)...

Comment: @sdleihssirhc "Write this code for me" is generally frowned upon. Or wildly upvoted. Sometimes both

Comment: I don't expect the code to be written for me...A break-down of the logic involved would be helpful and appreciated...

Comment: A question that starts with "I need ..." is an immediate red flag. The three similar questions mentioned above should have all the info you need.

Comment: Fair enough...I didn't mean to come across that way...Thanks mugur, that is exactly what I needed, very much appreciated...

Comment: This code does what I need:<?php
$days = date('t');
$curYear = date('Y');
$curMonth = date('M');;
$date = strtotime($curYear.'-'.$curMonth.'-01 next monday');
$dateMax = strtotime($curYear.'-'.$curMonth.'-'.$days);

$nbr = 0;
while ($date < $dateMax) {
  //var_dump(date('Y-m-d', $date));
  $nbr++;
  $date += 7 * 24 * 3600;
}

echo $nbr;
?>